# Jquery Chosen Plugin: Is that possible to trigger keyup event when user enter some text in search field?

Tags: jquery, json, plugins, jquery-chosen

I am trying to trigger an event of key(keypress/keyup) when a user enters some text in the chosen plugin search input field.

I want to get the list from the server-side by JSON call based on the text entered by the user.

In my case, I used it in a modal(popup), and below is my code.

```
function AddMedication()
{
    $('#ModalNewMedication').modal('show');

    $('#ModalNewMedication').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#ddlMedications', this).chosen();

        $('#ddlMedications').on('input', '.chosen-search input', function(event){
            alert('iam done');
        });

    });
}
```

I tried it many ways like on("keyUp", function(e){}) etc but failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".chosen-search input").on('keyup', function(e) {
      console.log($(this));
  })
```

Comment: It doesn't work